# How to copy all web driver properties and attach them to a new WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to execute some UI tests in parallel. These tests are in three classes that are included in a runner xml, like below:

[image]

This runner is used by Jenkins and I want to run the tests that are in the classes present in this xml in parallel.

Before starts all tests in parallel, I need to login into the app and copy all web driver properties (localstorage, sessionstorage and cookies) into the new web drivers, in this way I am able to stay logged in to run the tests into new browsers.

My application is single session and I can't login in multiple browsers instance because I'll be deconnected on the other session.

Is possible to "clone" the driver used for authentication?

I want to do this, because in a new tab, on instance I made authentication, I remaining authenticated, but if I open a new browser instance, I will be unauthenticated on it.

Comment: You can't use the same temp directory for different sessions.  While you can set the cookies using Selenium, you have to set them from the same domain, which can be problematic depending on the site and how/when it begins a new session.  Since this site only allows one session I'd expect some problems there.  Do you know the method the site uses to persist a session? (claims based?)

Comment: Here is a problem, for auth, I have a different domain like: www.example-auth.com and for application I have a domain like: www.example.com. By default, if a user is not authenticated, he is redirected to the auth page. We know if a user is authenticated if have a valid cookie and some properties in local storage.
It is possible to use only one driver and run tests on parallel (different tabs simultaneously) on browser in which we made login?

Comment: that is not possible.  You need one driver/browser pair per thread.

Comment: Ok, do you have any tips how to duplicate browser properties or what is the workaround for this problem? Thank you!

Comment: it'll depend on how the site persists the session.  It sounds like you should be using a separate account for each.

Comment: How do you suggest to manage the separate accounts for each driver? For example we have 4 threads(created by selenium) and 30 tests, how can we get control of each thread to access the user we want so we don't open 2 drivers with same users ?

Comment: you have to create the threads and use different username/passwords for each.  (If it's true that only one session can exist at a time....)